# Rebar3 : not able to install on windows 8

Tags: windows, erlang, rebar

I am trying to install rebar3 using the git console.I have erlang installed and the path is set to C:\Program Files\erl7.3\bin
 Here are the steps which I followed :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/erlang/rebar3.git 
$ cd rebar3 
$./bootstrap
```

On hitting bootstrap ,I get the following error

```
escript: exception throw: {error,{rebar_prv_update,package_index_write}}
in function  rebar_prv_update:do/1 (src/rebar_prv_update.erl, line 77)
in call from rebar_core:do/2 (src/rebar_core.erl, line 125)
in call from erl_eval:do_apply/6 (erl_eval.erl, line 670)
in call from escript:eval_exprs/5 (escript.erl, line 871)
in call from erl_eval:local_func/6 (erl_eval.erl, line 557)
in call from escript:interpret/4 (escript.erl, line 787)
in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
in call from init:start_it/1 (init.erl, line 1055)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I have the same error. Were you able to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following [github issue](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/issues/1168).

My user home directory was pointed to a network location. I removed the network location from My Computer and was able to build rebar3 successfully.